# gcloud sdk commands failing with dns.name.EmptyLabel: A DNS label is empty

Tags: dns, gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

Recently, I've had a recurring issue where either `gcloud` or `gsutil` command will fail with the following stacktrace.  They notably occur when switching from wired to wireless in the same terminal session.  However, they will occasionally happen without that taking place.  I'm running macOS 10.13.3 (High Sierra).

How can I remedy this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 19, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 31, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import http
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/http.py", line 32, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import session_capturer
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/session_capturer.py", line 34, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import yaml_printer
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/yaml_printer.py", line 21, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer_base
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 42, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_projector
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_projector.py", line 32, in <module>
    from apitools.base.py import encoding as protorpc_encoding
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apitools.base.py.credentials_lib import *
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py", line 44, in <module>
    import fasteners
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/fasteners/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from fasteners.lock import locked  # noqa
  File "/Users/USER_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/fasteners/lock.py", line 31, in <module>
    import eventlet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 390, in <module>
    resolver = ResolverProxy(hosts_resolver=HostsResolver())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 305, in __init__
    self.clear()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 308, in clear
    self._resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(filename=self._filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/dns/resolver.py", line 605, in __init__
    self.read_resolv_conf(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/dns/resolver.py", line 661, in read_resolv_conf
    self.search.append(dns.name.from_text(suffix))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/dns/name.py", line 821, in from_text
    raise EmptyLabel
dns.name.EmptyLabel: A DNS label is empty.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, this looks like a bug with `eventlet`, a dependency-of-a-dependency-of-a-dependency of gsutil :)

I'd recommend filing a bug on their GitHub repository:
https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet